# setTitle not working Android

Tags: java, android

I created a sliding tab activity and I am trying to dynamically change the title of the app bar. but what ever i do it doesnt seem to work! here is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ViewPager mPager;
SlidingTabLayout mTabs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_view, R.id.tabText);

    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

    mTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);

}

class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int tabIcons[] = {R.drawable.ic_events, R.drawable.ic_clients, R.drawable.ic_history};
    String[] tabText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Events");
                EventsFragment eventsFragment = EventsFragment.getInstance(position);
                return eventsFragment;

            case 1:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Clients");
                ClientsFragment clientsFragment = ClientsFragment.getInstance(position);
                return clientsFragment;

            case 2:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("History");
                HistoryFragment historyFragment = HistoryFragment.getInstance(position);
                return historyFragment;

            default:
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Events");
                EventsFragment defaultFragment = EventsFragment.getInstance(position);
                return defaultFragment;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(tabIcons[position]);

        drawable.setBounds(0,0,64,64);

        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);

        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(" ");

        spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return spannableString;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

}

I have also tried to set the title of the app bar in the `onCreate` method using:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Test");
```

which doesn't work either.

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Note: Whenever I try to do anything with the action bar such as setting a back arrow with: getSupportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); Nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call **setTitle** method on the **MainActivity** object.

Calling from within the **MainActivity**: just `setTitle(...)`. Calling from a different class (*MyPagerAdapter*):  `activity.setTitle(...)`

**activity** being a reference to the **MainActivity** object. You can use `getActivity()`, which returns the activity associated with a fragment.

In conclusion, use `getActivity().setTitle(...);` in order to set the title from within a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

here is code from one of my projects:

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((AboutActivity)context).getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_title_layout);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) actionBar.getCustomView();
TextView titleTextView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.page_title_layout);
titleTextView.setText("Your title");
titleTextView.setTypeface(Constants.TYPE_FACE_FONT_MEDIUM); // here you can customise your font
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

action_bar_title_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/page_title_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_ultralight"
        android:text="Title"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```